# Textbox bounding box with custom font is loaded incorrectly

Tags: canvas, textbox, fabricjs

I tried loading a new font to my FabricJS canvas. But when after it rendered, the text is placed incorrectly in relation to its bounding box. However, the size and positioning of the bounding box itself seem to be good, the content (text) is misplaced. I tried a number of things, including waiting for the font to properly load before setting the attributes of the textbox, but it wasn't completely successful, so I am turning to SO for further suggestions.

[image]